# Append comma after 10 digit and start new line

Tags: javascript, jquery

I need to add comma after end of the string in textarea and length of the string will be 10 digit + 1(',') using javascript

currently what I'm getting is

```
1234567890
1234567890
1234567890
```

Here is my code [JSFIDDLE](https://jsfiddle.net/SagarVirpara/jsf6qr9p/63/)

what I need is something like

```
1234567890,
1234567890,
1234567890
```

Thanks in advance.

```js
$('.number').keyup(function () {
    this.value = this.value
                     .replace(/[\n\r]+/g, "")
                     .replace(/(.{10})/g, "$1\n");
 
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<textarea class="number" style="width: 200px; height: 200px;">

</textarea>
```

Comment: check my answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just add additional comma in your replace statement. No need to add one more replace with the code as @Abdullah Shoaib mentioned.

```
$('.number').keyup(function () {
this.value = this.value
                 .replace(/[\n,\r]+/g, "")
                 .replace(/(.{10})/g, "$1,\n");

 });
```

**Snippet**

```js
$('.number').keyup(function () {
    this.value = this.value
                     .replace(/[\n,\r]+/g, "")
                     .replace(/(.{10})/g, "$1,\n");
 
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<textarea class="number" style="width: 200px; height: 200px;">
</textarea>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can add code for comma as below.

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<textarea class="number" style="width: 200px; height: 200px;">

</textarea>
<script src="jquery-2.2.3.min.js"></script>
<script>
  
$('.number').keyup(function () {
    this.value = this.value
                     .replace(/[,\n]/g, "")
                     .replace(/(.{10})/g, "$1,\n");
  
});
</script>
```

Comment: @SagarVirpara happy to help.  Don't forget to upvote the answer too.

Comment: Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 0):

Try this code

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<textarea class="number" style="width: 200px; height: 200px;">

</textarea>
<script src="jquery-2.2.3.min.js"></script>
<script>
  
$('.number').keyup(function () {
   var txt=$(this).val();
   txt=$.trim(txt);
   var artmp=txt.split("\n");
   var len=artmp.length;
   var lstline=artmp[len-1];
  if(lstline.length>9){
   lstline=lstline+',\n';
   }
   artmp[len-1]=lstline;
   $('.number').val(artmp.join("\n"));
});
</script>
```